# Absolute position in slide up

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div which contains an absolute positioned element which (on hover) slides up. This element contains text, as well as a button. This button needs to be positioned at the bottom, but not show until the content has slid up. I have tried to use position: absolute, but this displays the element all the time. I have also tried to apply position absolute at hover, but since I am using transitions, the element shows too early. Using transition delay works on the fade in, but then takes too long to disappear.

[Fiddle of example.](https://jsfiddle.net/t4usjrL2/)

```css
.div {
  background: #ccffcc;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
  padding: 0 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffccff;
}
.div:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
.div .overlay .cta {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2>Titel</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <span class="cta">
          <span>Read more</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you make your button position absolute it will be absolute to the relative parent. It won't be absolute in the the `.overlay` because `.overlay` is already position absolute. What you need to do is position the `.cta` off the screen just like `.overlay` and slide it up with `.overlay` using a similar transition. I've put comments above my changes

```css
.div {
  background: #ccffcc;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
  padding: 0 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffccff;
}
.div:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
.div .overlay .cta {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /* ===== Add Transition to CTA ===== */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* ===== Move bottom off screen ===== */
  bottom: -120px;
}
/* ===== Add :hover for CTA ===== */
.div:hover .cta {
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2>Titel</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <span class="cta">
          <span>Read more</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it `position: absolute`, better to make it `relative` & control the position that way. Just change your `.cta` to

```
.div .overlay .cta {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  width: 10%; //changed
  position: relative; //changed
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 53%; //changed
}
```

```css
.div {
  background: #ccffcc;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
  padding: 0 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffccff;
}
.div:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
.div .overlay .cta {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 53%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2>Titel</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <span class="cta">
          <span>Read more</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will have different amount of text in the <p>, so I would need to absolute position the cta, so that it always stays at the bottom.